# How to find a canonical basis $W^⊥$ knowing a basis of W and the scalar product associated with it?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know what is the general method to find a canonical basis of $W^⊥$
provided you know the basis of $W$ and the scalar product associated to the space.

It seems to me that this involves finding a vector/vectors that when scalar multiplied with the vectors of the basis of $W$ gives $0$ as the result. Basically finding an orthogonal vector to the basis. But, is it just that? Don't we have other things to verify can I just arbitrarily come up with that vector?

In some homework problem they provided me with a basis of $W$ that consists of one vector. In this case, is finding one arbitrary vector enough? How would the situation change if the basis of $W$ contains more than one vector? What makes 
 $W^⊥$ canonical or not ?

Comment: this is what I am asking also. What makes a basis canonical?

Comment: “Canonical” is whatever you decide it to be. What does your textbook consider canonical here?

Comment: The simplest basis you can find.

Comment: That just reduces it to another arbitrary and undefined term. How do _you_ measure simplicity in a basis?

Comment: There is no such thing as a “canonical basis”. The simplest way to find *a* basis for $W^{\perp}$ given a basis $\beta$ for $W$ is to first complete $\beta$ to a basis $\beta\cup\gamma$ for all $V$, and then apply Gram-Schmidt to this basis, with the vectors in $\beta$ first. If $\dim(W)=k$, then the first $k$ vectors of the resulting orthonormal basis are an orthonormal basis for $W$, and the rest are an orthonormal basis for $W^{\perp}$.

Comment: not sure what  ∪  mean

Comment: @ArturoMagidin At least as simple is to first orthogonalize the basis for $W$, then feed all of the standard basis vectors into G-S; discard any zeros that result.

Answer (score 1):

For specific vectors spaces, there might be some notion of a “canonical” basis for a subspace, but there’s no general definition of canonicity. In the same vein, there’s no generally accepted measure for what makes one basis “simpler” than another—that’s going to depend entirely on context.

That said, there are some straightforward ways to find a basis for $W^\perp$ given a basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ of a subspace $W$ of an inner product space $V$. Essentially, this comes down to finding a basis for the solution space of the system of homogeneous linear equations $\langle v_i,x\rangle = 0$. If you’re working with coordinate tuples, this amounts to finding a basis for the kernel of the coefficient matrix of this system.

As Arturo Magidin comments, you can instead complete $\mathcal B$ to a basis for the ambient space $V$ and then apply the Gram-Schmidt process to it, using the elements of $\mathcal B$ first. The first $m$ vectors that result will comprise an orthogonal (orthonormal) basis of $W$, and the remaining vector an orthogonal (orthonormal) basis of $W^\perp$. Actually, if you have *any* complete basis $\mathcal B'$ of $V$ handy, you can apply G-S to the concatenation of $\mathcal B$ and this basis. Again, after the first $m$ iterations you’ll have an orthogonal basis for $W$. As you continue the process with $\mathcal B'$, discard any zeros that result; the nonzero vectors will be an orthogonal basis of $W^\perp$.